# iOS: NSString keeps going null

Tags: ios, nsstring, null, tableview

This is an odd issue that I can't seem to resolve.

In my app I'm using a tableviewcontroller for an array of custom objects (with string titles), and in the showDetailsForIndexPath method I assign the object's string value to a class variable I've called chosenString. This is synthesised (with just nonatomic) and in the aforementioned method the value is successfully set. When it comes to another method in the same class called PrepareForSegue the chosenString is now null. What am I missing here?

This is how I've declared it in the header file (just extracts, this isn't how the header file looks)

```
    NSString *chosenString;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *chosenString;
```

I assume the * means that it's being initiated so there's no need to do so in the source file?

Comment: Since when does `*` mean that an object is auto-initialized? Someone give me THAT version of objc, please.

Comment: I am, Richard. And I apologise, that's just a quick thought that came to mind because I'm otherwise stumped.

Comment: I think the scoping for your variable may be off, and the reason that its turning to null after the method in which you initialize and set it is that its being released, which I think where Richard was headed. I don't have the greatest grasp on ARC yet, but try to change your property declaration to (nonatomic, weak) or strong. I think it might default to weak, and that may be your problem? Just something I would play with, if I said something incorrect feel free to correct me.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but how are you setting the titles? Have you verified that there are actually values in your array, and that they have correct values? Maybe its they that are getting released early.

Comment: @KarolyS no, properties default to `strong` if they are objects in ARC, and `assign` if they are not objects.

Comment: Okay so I guess that's not it then, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa/UIKIt objects need to use "strong" in the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *chosenString;
```